# Laravel CSS and JS file not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am having a laravel project when I start the server the **CSS** and **JS** file are not getting loaded.

Its working fine in **windows** but **ubuntu** it's not working. i have created a virtual host and specified the project path but still, it's not working.

When i remove the **public** from the below URL it's working fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/public/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Virtual host Document Root Path :- */var/www/laravel-app/public*
This is how I had defined my css :- `

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/public/css/bootstrap.css')}}">`
```

In the above URL if I use *../css/bootsratp.css* it's working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console

Answer (score 0):

1. Laravel has its own server. Run it this way

```
        php artisan serve
```

2. Use helper function `asset()` to get the full URI of your file

```
        asset('css/style.css')
```

Comment: That is fine....how can i make it work with '/public/css/bootstrap.css' URL ..By virtual host is it possible ?why it is not working now ?

Comment: I'm not sure which VH you are using and which OS you are using.

1. Run php artisan serve
2. Add the file /pubic/css/style.css 
3. Include the file as I wrote below

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

For CSS:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Make your directory structure is like this for CSS: */public/css/bootstrap.css*

Comment: That is fine....how can i make it work with '/public/css/bootstrap.css' URL ..By virtual host is it possible ?

Comment: @VivekSharma If you don't want index.php inside /public you will need to use public/ inside your asset path, like this: asset("public/css/bootstrap.css")

Comment: My question is how it is working in windows with exact same configuration but not in ubuntu ?

Comment: I don't have experience with Ubuntu but this can work in windows like this

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel all your asset files are at your project's public folder

Laravel has a function to point to the public folder

```
asset("css/style.css")
```

output

```
/projectfloder/public/css/style.css
```